# max and Min functions issue In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> d="programing"
>>> min(d)
'a'
>>> d="123456Ed"
>>> min(d)
'1'
>>> max(d)
'd'
```

Why max function returning d however E is the highest character is there in that string.

```
>>> e="123456eeE"
>>> min(e)
'1'
```

Here Why min function returns 1 however e is the smallest character is there in string.

Comment: Why do you think `'e' < '1'` or `'d' < 'E'`?

Comment: Ah, it's not the *position* in the string matters.

Answer (score 0):

`'E' < 'd'` because capital letters come first in the ASCII table.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's Unicode that matters; the first 128 code points correspond to ASCII, though.

Answer (score 0):

`min()` and `max()` use compare the elements between them; in case of chars/strings the Unicode values are used.

The numeric values of some chars in your example string `'123456eeE'` are (using the build-in function [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)):

```
>>> ord('1')
49
>>> ord('e')
101
>>> ord('E')
69
```

So there is no surprise here:

```
>>> min('123456eeE')
'1'
>>> max('123456eeE')
'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use min() on a string it automatically returns the character closest to the beginning of the alphabet, which starts withs special chars and then numbers and then letters. Its based off the ASCII table found [Here](http://www.asciitable.com/)